# Why is $HOME/.config/git/credentials ignored when semantic-release do git push

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, semantic-release

I am using **git 2.19.0** and I have my release CI job failing.

I want to authenticate using git [git-credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store#git-credential-store-XDGCONFIGHOMEgitcredentials).

This is how I create my [$HOME/.config/git/credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store#git-credential-store-XDGCONFIGHOMEgitcredentials)

```
if [[ "${CI_PROJECT_URL}" =~ (([^/]*/){3}) ]]; then
  mkdir -p $HOME/.config/git
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]/:\/\//://gitlab-ci-token:${GL_TOKEN:-$GITLAB_TOKEN}@}" > $HOME/.config/git/credentials
  git config --global credential.helper store
fi
```

This is what I have in `.git/config`:

```
[fetch]
    recurseSubmodules = false
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.example.com/some-org/some-project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

This is what I have in `$HOME/.config/git/credentials`:

```
$ cat $HOME/.config/git/credentials
https://gitlab-ci-token:Dwq456WQd4q56QW@git.example.com/
```

However, when I do `git push`, it fails to use that configuration, instead it read the one from `.git/config` within the project.

Doing `cp $HOME/.config/git/credentials ~/.git-credentials` did not help.

Why would a [$HOME/.config/git/credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store#git-credential-store-XDGCONFIGHOMEgitcredentials) would be ignored when I do `git push`?

Comment: What's the relevant configuration in `.git/config` that you think might be overriding this?

Comment: In Gitlab-CI, the git strategy is a git fetch, the url used within `.git/config` is a https url including a read only project token. I have tried to `git set remote-url origin https://myproject.git` so it remove the credential here but that doesn't make the git credential store used either.